# Trying to write the division algorithm in Sympy which apparently has its own truth (Boolean variables)

Tags: algorithm, boolean, sympy, division

So I was trying to write out the code to perform the one variable polynomial division algorithm using the open source SymPy. It already has a leading term function, so I thought it would be easy. The book, *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms* by Cox, Little and O'Shea gives the pseudo-code to be:

```
Input: g, f
Output: q, r
q := 0; r := f
WHILE r <> 0 AND LT (g) divides LT (r ) DO
    q := q + LT (r )/ LT (g)
    r := r − ( LT (r )/ LT (g))g
```

So my python code is:

```
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')

f= x**4-5*x**2-2*x+7
g = 3*x**2 + 4*x - 2

q = 0 
r = f
while (r != 0 & degree(g) < LT(r ) ):
    q = q + LT (r )/ LT (g)
    r = r - ( LT (r )/ LT (g))*g

print(q,r)
```

But this gives an error message: *TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'Integer'*. So in the console, I query `type(r != 0)` and it gives *bool*, but for `type(degree(g) < degree(r))`, it gives *sympy.logic.boolalg.BooleanTrue*. I tried to look up the documentation for *sympy.logic.boolalg.BooleanTrue*, and I couldn't find how to make it an object so that I can combine with a bool using a logical &.

Why does sympy have its own boolean variables and how do I get it to play well with the normal boolean variables?

Answer (score 1):

SymPy has its own `Boolean` class because needs to be used in the `Basic` expression construction and needs to support methods like `subs` etc to be used consistently in the SymPy architecture.

The `Boolean` type can be used with `bool` e.g.:

```
In [7]: S.true & True                                                                                                             
Out[7]: True

In [8]: S.true and True                                                                                                           
Out[8]: True
```

The problem in your example is actually to do with operator preference:

```
In [9]: r != 0 & degree(g) < LT(r )                                                                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-f2737cccd83e> in <module>
----> 1 r != 0 & degree(g) < LT(r )

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'Integer'

In [10]: (r != 0) & (degree(g) < LT(r))                                                                                           
Out[10]: 
     4
2 < x 


In [11]: r != (0 & degree(g)) < LT(r)                                                                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-c7a6030e1401> in <module>
----> 1 r != (0 & degree(g)) < LT(r)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'Integer'
```

It is `0 & degree(g)` which is evaluated first and SymPy's `Integer` type can not be used with `&` which is used for symbolic "and" in SymPy:

```
In [14]: (x<1) & (x>-1)                                                                                                           
Out[14]: x > -1 ∧ x < 1
```

You probably meant to use Python's `and` operator which has a lower precedence than `&`:

```
In [15]: r != 0 and degree(g) < LT(r)                                                                                             
Out[15]: 
     4
2 < x
```

This will not actually work though in the `while` loop because the `Boolean` expression is indeterminate:

```
---> 10 while (r != 0 and degree(g) < LT(r ) ):
     11     q = q + LT (r )/ LT (g)
     12     r = r - ( LT (r )/ LT (g))*g

~/current/sympy/sympy/sympy/core/relational.py in __nonzero__(self)
    382 
    383     def __nonzero__(self):
--> 384         raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
    385 
    386     __bool__ = __nonzero__

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

This is because the truth of the condition is unknowable:

```
In [18]: degree(g) < LT(r)                                                                                                        
Out[18]: 
     4
2 < x
```

I think what you meant to check there is `rem(LT(g), LT(r)) == 0`.

```
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')

f= x**4-5*x**2-2*x+7
g = 3*x**2 + 4*x - 2

q = 0
r = f
while (r != 0 and rem(LT(g), LT(r)) == 0):
    q = q + LT (r )/ LT (g)
    r = r - ( LT (r )/ LT (g))*g

print(q,r)
```

Output:

```
0 x**4 - 5*x**2 - 2*x + 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much, Oscar (though I still don't understand the need for the sympy boolean to be different). Your response allowed me to find other issues and the following code works (which is in function form):

```
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')

# the division algorithm, returns the quotient and remainder

def DivAlg(f,g):   
    q = 0   # quotient
    r = f   # remainder

    while (r != 0) & (degree(g) <= degree(r)):
        q = q + LT(r)/LT(g) 
        r = r - expand(( LT(r)/LT(g)) * g) # the expand command is necessary!

    return [q,r]
```

Can try `DivAlg(x**4-x**3-4*x**2-5*x-3, x**2+3*x-5)`.

I also used this to write a function that uses the Euclidean algorithm to find the GCD of two one-variable polynomials:

```
def GCD(f,g):
    h = f
    s = g
    while (s!= 0):
        r = DivAlg(h,s)[1]
        h = s
        s = r
    return h/LC(h)  # LC(h) is the coefficient of highest order term.
```

You can try it out with `print(GCD(x**3-x**2-x-2,x**4-x**3-4*x**2-5*x-3))`.

This is the code needed to do problem 1.5.8 (p. 46) of the fun book, *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms* by Cox, Little, and O'Shea. I should note that sympy - of course - already has an implementation of this with the following command: `gcd(x**3-x**2-x-2,x**4-x**3-4*x**2-5*x-3,domain=QQ)`